# How to correctly download files to Angular from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a file on the server that I want to send to the client:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(FilesFolder, "test.docx"));
    return File(bytes, _contentTypeWord);
}
```

I also tried with

```
return PhysicalFile(pathUploadFile, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

At the client I accept using:

```
private _downloadFile(data: ArrayBuffer, fileName: string, contentType: string) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

public test() {
    this.http.post("Diplom/Test", { }, {
        headers: this.headers(),
    }).subscribe(
        result => {
            this._downloadFile(result.arrayBuffer(), "test.docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
        },
        error => {
            alert("Не удалось отредактировать файл");
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        })
}
```

The file that the client receives is corrupt and does not open. The file that is on the server is fine and opens perfectly. The resulting file still does not open, and even weighs 2 times more (on the server 487 KB, and the client has 925 KB).

Comment: Try sending it base64 encoded between your backend and client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know why the option specified in the question does not work. But I found a solution, so to say "in another forest". I'm not very versed, so I'll just describe the process of solving the problem. For the beginning I will immediately say that the problem was on the client's side. The method on the server worked correctly from the start.
I decided to use another method to download the files "fetch". And came across the next post in the [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168090/fetch-api-to-force-download-file). From there I took the following answer

```
this.httpClient
    .fetch(url, {method, body, headers})
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    .then(url => {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
```

He did not work for me either. I changed it so

```
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: this.headers()
        })
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .then(url => {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
```

Because of this line nothing happened

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

This option worked, but with screwed. He saved the file with a strange name and no extension. Then I changed it so.

```
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: this.headers()
        })
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
            .then(url => {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                link.setAttribute("download", "test.docx");
                link.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
```

And it works!
I apologize for the English. I'm using Google translator

Comment: Thanks it works, I used your method with HttpClient.Get :    

```
    this.http.get(path`, {responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(file=> {
        const url:string = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", "Template.xlsx");
        link.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to append the child to the body (and therefore also to remove it). Just `link.click()` is enough

Answer (score 18):

You can use a file result and just provide an api link that will return a [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

```
public IActionResult Download(// some parameter) 
{
   // get the file and convert it into a bytearray
   var locatedFile = ....
   return new FileContentResult(locatedFile, new 
       MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet"))
       {
           FileDownloadName = "SomeFileDownloadName.someExtensions"
       };
}
```

Now you only need to provide the link and browser will know how to handle it. No need to do it yourself then.

**Edit:**
I just tested this approach with angular, you need to do the following to download the file when using angulars [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

First you need to install file-saver via npm.

```
npm i --save file-saver
```

Then in your module import and include HttpClientModule

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      HttpClientModule
      ...
   ]
...
})
```

Now go ahead to your service and do the following

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Injectable()
export class MyFileService {

   public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

       public downloadFile() {
    this.http.get('my-api-url', { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(blob => {
       saveAs(blob, 'SomeFileDownloadName.someExtensions', {
          type: 'text/plain;charset=windows-1252' // --> or whatever you need here
       });
    });
}
```

Then blob is handled and a file-save dialog is created.

Comment: It did not help

Comment: Why not, what happened?

Comment: Nothing. In class MediaTypeHeaderValue did not find properties FileDownloadName. All the same damage file comes

Comment: It&amp;#39;s a property of FileConentResult, not MediaTypeHeaderValue. Could you please provide the dotnet code?

Comment: There's the same code. Only when sending a file I inserted the code from your example

Comment: So you still have the same code in the frontend? Then that is the fault, you don't need the front-end code anymore. Just try to access the api url via the browser and see if the file is correctly downloaded. If not, the file must damaged.

Comment: Yes. If you go to the method stupidly through the address bar, everything is fine

Comment: That is how you should download the file from the front-end too. Just access the link via a http.get method, browser will do the work.

Comment: I don’t understand how to modify the method in TypeScript. If you leave it as it’s, does not work. But it’s easy to make a link to the method I can not, since there headings and the body need to be treated

Comment: I updated the post with an example how to use it with angular 4.3++

Comment: This was actually very helpful. Wow I have searched for this for almost the whole day. Thanks

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To download any file, first install the following,

```
npm install rxjs --save
npm install file-saver --save
```

Include these packages in your component(Angular 2+),

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpEventType, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Front-end code,

```
<input type="button" placeholder="Download" value="Download" (click)="download(file)" />
```

Angular Code,

```
download(file) {
        let fileName = file;
        let checkFileType = fileName.split('.').pop();
        var fileType;
        if (checkFileType == ".txt") {
            fileType = "text/plain";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".pdf") {
            fileType = "application/pdf";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".doc") {
            fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".docx") {
            fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".xls") {
            fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".png") {
            fileType = "image/png";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".jpg") {
            fileType = "image/jpeg";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".jpeg") {
            fileType = "image/jpeg";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".gif") {
            fileType = "image/gif";
        }
        if (checkFileType == ".csv") {
            fileType = "text/csv";
        }
        this.DownloadFile(fileName, fileType)
            .subscribe(
                success => {
                    saveAs(success, fileName);
                },
                err => {
                    alert("Server error while downloading file.");
                }
            );
    }

    DownloadFile(filePath: string, fileType: string): Observable<any> {

        let fileExtension = fileType;
        let input = filePath;

        return this.http.get(this.yourApiUrl + "?fileName=" + input, {
            responseType: 'blob',
            observe: 'response'
        })
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => {
                    return new Blob([res.body], { type: fileExtension });
                })
            );
    }
```

.NET Core API code,

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<FileStream> DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            return new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593490/read-file-and-its-properties-from-api-and-download-it-in-angular-client