# Convert byte array into blob (pdf file) and download using angular 5

Tags: asp.net-core, angular5

I'm receiving a byte array from server side and has converted it successfully to blob. However, when I'm trying to download it, it shows the file is corrupted. Below are my codes -

```
// In client side controller
this.contractsService.downloadPdf(id)
      .then((result) => {
        var blob = new Blob([result], { type: "application/pdf" });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "testing.pdf";
        link.click();
      });
```

And,

```
// In client side service
private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
downloadPdf(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiRoutes.download + "/" + id, { headers: this.headers })
      .map((res: any) => res)
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Any sort of help will be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look into the documentation for the http client that does the ajax request. You need to make sure that the generated `result` is a Blob (treated as binary) and not a string (treated with shenanigans and evil encodings). This is probably another parameter or setting to the `this.http.get(...)` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

```
npm i --save file-saver@latest
```

Your service method

```
downloadPdf(id: number) {
    return this.http
              .get(this.apiRoutes.download + "/" + id, { responseType:'blob' })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Now in your component

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'

this.contractsService.downloadPdf(id)
      .then(blob=> {
         saveAs(blob, 'testing.pdf');
      });
```

This should do the trick. The HttpClient will now extract the file from the stream. Also have a look in the documentation for blobs with the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

Comment: When you open the url of your api directly via browser and download the file, does it work? Either u are using legacy http client or the file that is served is corrupt in the first place.

Comment: When I'm downloading the file on the server side locally, it works perfectly. However, when I'm converting it to byte array and sending to the client side for downloading, it's getting corrupted.
P.S. no, the file is showing corrupted when I open it manually from the URL as well.

Comment: Ah okay, then it is your API that is doing wrong, not the client.

Comment: Locally as in, when I create the file using File class.

Comment: Yeah is the API that ir returning the file corrupted, is not the client. Provide the API code and I may help you.

Comment: Is there any possible way to download the file from angular 5, "without" creating a temporary file on the server side?

Comment: You don't need to provide a temporary file, just a byte array and a filecontent-result. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864842/5397642

Comment: Thanks a lot. FileContentResult was the thing that I was missing and I didn't know about it either. However, using it, resolved the issue. Still, can you please clarify a bit about FileContentResult class?
Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: It's just a class that implements IActionResult and returns a file as byte array. Will set special response headers like content-disposition, file name and so on. You can read more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 0):

In client side service, try explicitly setting the response type of the get request:

```
downloadPdf(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.apiRoutes.download + "/" + id, { headers: this.headers; responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .map((res: any) => res)
      .toPromise();
  }
```