# how get byte array in tempdata[""] and set img scr in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-core

im use mvc core2 .and get imge profile and show  img src and store sessionStorage browser
iam use Tempdata[""] and get image jquery but show

> "system,byte"

dont show any binary

this code

```
TempData["img"] = user.LoginUserInfo.Picture as byte[];
```

html code

```
var img = '@TempData["img"]';
sessionStorage.setItem('imguser', img);
$('#img').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," +    sessionStorage.getItem("imguser"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the byte[] to a base64string.

```
var base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray);
```

Then store this in you tempdata and use it as image-source.

A better way would be to have a route that provides a filecontent-result and then just embedded the url as source, because a base64 string increases the size of the image.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864518/how-to-correctly-download-files-to-angular-from-asp-net-core/48864842#48864842) for instance.