# How to have the dialog box for choosing download location appeared in the frontend, before the file gets downloaded, using FastAPI?

Tags: javascript, python, html, download, fastapi

I have a `GET` endpoint that should return a **huge file** (500Mb).
I am using `FileResponse` to do that (the code is simplified for clarity reasons):

```
 async def get_file()
       headers = {"Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={filename}"}
       return FileResponse(file_path, headers=headers)
```

The problem is that I have to wait on the frontend until that file is **completely** downloaded, in order for the dialog box for choosing a download location to be shown:
[image]

And then this file is saved instantly.

So, for example, I have a file with size 500 MB, when I click download on UI I have to wait a minute or something till the "Save dialog" is displayed. Then, when I click "Save" the file is saved instantly. Obviously, the frontend was waiting for the file to be downloaded.

**What I need is this**: The dialog to be shown instantly and then the user waiting for the file downloading to finish, **after** the user clicks 'Save' to choose the download location. So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can do it via Background task in fastAPI https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects ? It might be the local reading of the file that's the issue, not the delivery of the file - and no, background tasks run in the background after the client has disappeared, and wouldn't be a solution to this I think?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) helpful as well

Comment: I can see that BackgroundTasks are used mostly for doing something after the response is returned. I need to return a response right away, so the download dialog is opened on the client side. And the download is done in that dialog.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Overview

You haven't provided any details, regarding the client side of your project, but it seems that the client is most likely requesting the resource (file) using an asynchronous JavaScript request, such as a [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) request. If you are using Swagger UI autodocs, it also uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) behind the scenes—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804).

When requesting such a large file (500 MB), or any resource, using `fetch()` or any other asynchronous JavaScript library (as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804)), the response from the server **has to be completely received**, before further proceeding with showing the dialog box/window to choose the location, where you would like the file to be downloaded (see the linked answer provided earlier for the Swagger UI case).

Hence, instead of using JavaScript to request the resource, you could achieve having the dialog box for choosing the download location showed up beforehand, using the following approach.

### Solution

#### Backend

Setting the `filename` argument of `FileResponse`, for example:

```
return FileResponse(file_path, filename="BigFile.zip")
```

would add the `Content-Disposition` response header with the `attachment` flag, indicating that the file should be downloaded instead of viewed in the browser. If, however, you would like to be certain about it, you could add the `Content-Disposition` header to the response on your own, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), and as shown below:

```py
@app.get("/download")
def download_file():
    file_path = "files/BigFile.zip"
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="BigFile.zip"'}
    return FileResponse(file_path, headers=headers)
```

#### Frontend

On the frontend, you could simply use a hyperlink, defined by the `<a>` tag:

```html
<a href="/download">Download</a>
```

In case the backend did not set the `Content-Disposition` response header with the `attachment` flag included, you could use the `download` attribute in the hyperlink on the frontend, which "specifies that the target (the file specified in the href attribute) **will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink**" (see [related w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)):

```html
<a href="/download" download>Download</a>
```

##### Using a `<button>` instead of `<a>` hyperlink

If you needed having the user to click on a button instead of a hyperlink, you could use one of the following:

```html
<button>
<a href="/download" style="text-decoration: none; color: unset; cursor: default;" download>Download</a>
</button>
```

or

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('my_link').click()">Download</button>
<a id="my_link" href="/download" download hidden></a>
```

or

```html
<form method="get" action="/download">
 <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

or

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='/download'">Download</button>
```

**Note:** In the case of the last two options above, remember to set the `Content-Disposition` response header with the `attachment` flag on server side, so that the file gets downloaded instead of viewed in the browser, as you can't add the `<a>` hyperlink `download` attribute in those cases.

##### Initiate the file download through JavaScript

If you needed to initiate/trigger the file download through a JavaScript function, you could use the below. The `<button>` element below is optional; you could remove it, if you don't need the user to click on a button, but, instead, would like to automatically trigger the file downloading through a JS function.

```html
<a id="my_link" href="/download" download hidden></a>
<button onClick="downloadFile()">Download</button>
<script>
   function downloadFile() {
     document.getElementById("my_link").click()
   }
</script>
```