# Create a text file for download based on results of a database query in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a Flask form to query a database to retrieves entries by country and stores the results as a `results` object. Then, these entries are displayed using a jinja2 template I named `list.html` by passing `results` using `render_template`.

Now, I want to dynamically create a text file (or tabbed-delimited file for example) containing these retrieved entries so that it can be downloaded.

First, how do you dynamically create such a text file in Flask? Then, how do you create a link to download this dynamically-created file and include it in the jinja2 template?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166970/in-python-using-flask-how-can-i-write-out-an-object-for-download

Comment: This is useful but how do I pass the `results` object from the view that retrieves and displays the results to the view that creates the text file?

Comment: you can generate this file in your `views` rather to cluttering with `template`.  it will increase the complexity. the above example should help to attain.